# Can not see crash log in Device in Xcode but it is on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

My app crashed. I can see log in `System Preferences > Privacy > Diagnostics & Usage` I even can export it. But when connecting device to `Xcode`, I can not find it in `Device` panel. Why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does the phone trust the computer? Disconnect USB and reconnect - it should prompt you.  If iTunes is open, close it and Xcode, disconnect and reconnect USB.